# Send a MailMessage to an outlook group c#

Tags: c#, mailmessage

I've been sending emails to individuals and it did work fine. Now i'd like to send an email to an outlook group, it's not coming up with any error but simply people are not getting the email?

```
this.From = this.From ?? new MailAddress("blabla@bla.co.uk", "BLABLA");
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Port = 25;
        client.Host = "bla-co-uk.mail.protection.outlook.com";
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Send(this);

var mail = new MyMailMessage
            {
                Subject = "New Subject",
                Body = "Body"
            };

mail.To.Add("mygroup@blabla.com");
mail.Send();
```

Comment: When you say people aren't getting it, do you mean some people aren't getting it or no one in the group gets it?

Comment: @dman2306 Literally nobody is getting the message.

Comment: To be honest then, it sounds like an Exchange issue (I assume when you say Outlook group you mean Exchange group? If it's something you setup in your own MS Outlook and not on the server, that won't work). It doesn't sound like a problem with your C# code. Something you could do is try to send the message by just connecting via telnet (SMTP commands are simple). That might shed some light. See http://www.wikihow.com/Send-Email-Using-Telnet for info on how to do that. Another thing you can do is, if possible, ask the Exchange admin to check logs.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add your domain alias to the group name, BLABLA@bla.co.uk, because BLABLA is invalid email address, you can't use just the name